# C++ template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I have the following struct:

```
struct foo
{
    bool operator()(char a, char b) const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

pattern<char, foo> p;
```

And I have the following template class:

```
template<class T, class S = T>
class pattern
{
public:
    int fooBar(std::string lhs, std::string rhs)
    {
         if(equals(lhs, rhs)) { /* ... */ }
    }
private:
    bool equals(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) const
    {
        S s;
        if(s(lhs[0], rhs[0])  //"Term does not evaluate to a
                              // function taking 2 arguments"
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

My problem is, that I get the above error. So the question is, how can I reach the functor defined in the `foo` struct?

Comment: You need an instance of `foo` to call it: `foo s; s( 'a', 'b' );`

Comment: Declare an instance of `foo` and then call it with two `char` arguments? Your question doesn't make much sense. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do instead?

Comment: You call it from your function.

Comment: Your code compiles correctly for me, with the addition of `)` to the line `if(s(lhs[0], rhs[0])`, and putting the first block after the second block, and `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you've shown, `foo::operator()` **requires an instance** of `foo`.  It's not a `static` function.

And `pattern<T,S>` **does not hold an instance** of `T` or `S`.

You can call `foo::operator()` by instantiating `foo` somewhere.

```
bool equals(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) const
{
    return S{}(lhs, rhs);
    //      ^^ create a temporary instance, for example.  
}
```